# pyside Toggle resize capability

Tags: python, qlayout, pyside6

I have a qdialog with a button that when is pressed will show a lineText.

This work fine but I wold like that the qdialog is sizeable when the text edit is shown otherwise not

this is the code I use to toggle the visibility of the lineEdit

```
class AdvancedErrorPopUP(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, message="Error !!", messageBody="", mess_type='warning'):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        messageShortError = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        hlay.addWidget(messageShortError)
        more_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('More')
        more_button.clicked.connect(self.showMore)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setHidden(True)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumHeight(500)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumWidth(650)
        if len(messageBody) > 60 or len(message) > 60:
            hlay.addWidget(more_button)
            hlay.addItem(QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding) )
            more_button.setStyleSheet('background-color:white;')
            messageShortError.setText(message[:60])
            messageBody = message + messageBody
        else:
            messageShortError.setText(message)
            
        self.lineEdit.setHtml(messageBody)
        
        closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close")
        closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(hlay)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(closeButton)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        color = 'white'
        mess_type = mess_type.upper()
        if mess_type == 'ERROR':
            color = '#f44336'
        elif mess_type == 'WARNING':
            color = '#ffb600'
        elif mess_type == 'INFO':
            color = '#5bd3ff'
        self.setWindowTitle("%s!!" % (mess_type.capitalize()))
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color:%r;' % (color))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet('background-color:white;')
        closeButton.setStyleSheet('background-color:white;')
        messageShortError.setStyleSheet('font-weight: bold;')
        self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize);
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resizeMe)

    def showMore(self):
        lineTextHidden = not self.lineEdit.isHidden()
        self.lineEdit.setHidden(lineTextHidden)
        if lineTextHidden:
            self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize);
        else: # we are maximaizing
            self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetNoConstraint);
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resizeMe)

    def resizeMe(self):
        self.resize(self.minimumSizeHint())
```

as in example I use self.layout().setSizeConstraint fro changing the value but it dose not affect the resize behaviour

Comment: Please don't edit question to provide answers, as they make the post very confusing, so please remove the edit and use it for a new answer instead. Also your code is not very appropriate (setting an arbitrary "big size" isn't very useful): if you want to hide a widget, in normal conditions, you should *actually* hide it, not set its maximum sizes to 0. Also: use `setMaximumSize` instead of `setMaximumWidth` *and* `setMaximumHeight`, and setting a maximum size on a parent that is the same as the child is pointless (and inconsistent).

Comment: I try to hide it, but once I call the hide method, the dialog dose not allow to modifies the dimension !!! The solution proposed is the only one that works (At least for me). I edit the question as you suggest .. regards

Comment: If an answer doesn't work as expected, then ***tell it*** in the comments of that answer, so please add a comment there and specify where is the problem and whether you actually used my code or tried to do some modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem using the following code

```
def showMore(self):
    self._lineEditVisible = not self._lineEditVisible
    if self._lineEditVisible:
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(600, 400)
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumHeight(12000)
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumWidth(12000)
        self.setMaximumSize(12000,12000)
    else:
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(0, 0)
        self.setMaximumSize(1200, 100)
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumHeight(0)
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumWidth(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of setting the size constraint is that the top level window could have it's minimum and/or maximum sizes overridden.

Consider that `setSizeConstraint` is normally not used in normal situations (it's generally used for *custom* layout subclasses) nor it's generally called again once the layout has been activated, and also that setting it to `SetNoConstraint` will *not* reset the above min/max sizes if those values have been explicitly set or implicitly set by a previous `setSizeConstraint` call.

You also don't need to call `resize` based on the hint, if the size constraint and min/max sizes have been properly (re)set. The trick is to properly reset the maximum size whenever you want to allow resizing, and that's by using the maximum possible widget size returned by `QtWidgets.QWIDGETSIZE_MAX` (which is 16777215, 2^24).

```
class AdvancedErrorPopUP(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, message="Error !!", messageBody="", mess_type='warning'):
        # ...
        self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)

    def showMore(self):
        lineTextVisible = self.lineEdit.isHidden()
        self.lineEdit.setVisible(lineTextVisible)
        if lineTextVisible:
            self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
            self.setMaximumSize(QtWidgets.QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QtWidgets.QWIDGETSIZE_MAX)
        else:
            self.layout().setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
```

Comment: Thanks, I Update the question with my solutions